# Does headless chrome support MacOS native notification?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

Does headless Chrome support MacOS native notification? It seems the notification does not work when in the headless mode.

I was using Python3+selenium+chromedriver to develop a Gmail/Google Calendar notifier with headless Chrome running in the background, alerting me when emails or new events come. However, when I add `--headless` parameter, there was no notification when I received new emails.

```py
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=session")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
    })

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '/drivers/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

# Login manually or with existed cookies.
try:
    driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin')
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 600)
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('x7WrMb'))
    # Login succeeds. Close the window and open a headless window.
except Exception as e:
    print('Login fail: {e}'.format(e=e))
    driver.close()

# Open a headless Chrome and check new emails.
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '/drivers/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://gmail.com")

import time
time.sleep(100)
```

I expect the headless chrome can show me new emails coming in with notification.